# image cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, eclipse, image

I wrote an application in Android using eclipse, and it used to run perfectly fine. After I added an AVD (Android 2.3.3), it forced me to update my SDK tools. There were a lot of problems but this one is killing me.
As I said, it was ok but now, after the update, it has this error in my R.java file.

```
      public static final int Select Image From Gallery=0x7f040002;
```

in this line, I have these errors:  "image cannot be resolved to a type." and "Syntax error on token "Image",;expected"

I believe the problem is still from eclipse but it's been a long time I'm working on it and I can't get my head straight.

Any suggestion?!

Comment: Is this an ID of an element?

Comment: Rebuild the project and then try again.

Comment: `Select Image From Gallery` is not a legal identifier (variable) name.  It should be `SelectImageFromGallery` and to use correct Java naming conventions, `selectImageFromGallery`

Comment: @ManuelPires: I don't think so, it is generated automatically and my element ID is           targetimage.

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah: it didn't work, thanks for your concern anyway.

Comment: @Simon: thanks, but since it is in R.java, any changes will be undone once I want to run it.

Comment: You need to search in your xml code if you have an ID with this name, or Layout File and change it, removing the spaces or adding '_' between the words...

Comment: thank you all for your concerns, but as I said, it was running fine before, I checked the xml code and it was just fine. Unless I have to add something else to it, this is my xml code for my image:
         <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/targetimage"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          />